# systemd-networkd: Static address not added during boot

Tags: systemd, ipv6, systemd-networkd

I have a `.network` file for my `eth0` device:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Address]
Address=XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::617/64
```

When I boot the system, the interface gets an IPv4 and IPv6 address through DHCP, but the `XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::617/64` address does not show up on the interface. However when I run `systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service` later, the address is added correctly.

How can I convince systemd to add the address upon boot? This is on Debian Bullseye with systemd 247